# Angular 2 - strange effect with menu items click - opens # ref

Tags: angular

I need to develop 5-7 Angular applications each in own "location". For example:

- main app = /
- app1 = /orders
- app2 = /scheduler
- app3 = /transport
- etc.

And then I need to open links to these "sub-applications" from main app. Like this: click a link in *main app* and it should open */orders application* in new window.

The problem is - I'm not sure if this is possible at all with Angular 6 or not?
And how exactly to achieve that?

I tried to play with < base href="orders" > (tried it with and without slashes) but that did not help. Because all internal menus, tabs and navigation links in such Angular application does not work. :-( 
Also tried to build app with "ng build --prod --base-href orders" command - that also did not help (with the same problem).

I will give you example of problem I faced. In "/orders" app I have a menu like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" >
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  [...]
```

But when I open that in web-browser and click that menu link it fails, because it jumps to "http://myDevSrv.local/orders/orders#" location which is not exists, so it shows 404 HTTP error.

**Note**: this is just a default new application (I just created with "ng new orders" command) and only thing I did there - executed "ng install popper.js jquery bootstrap" command and added a menu example to app.component.html. So, app is very simple. I just need a max-simplified proof-of-concept working.

Could you please advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the order app work with ng serve?

Comment: I've never tried it but it certainly _should_ work. The `base` option is used exactly for that. Note that for navigation between apps you need to use `href` and not `routerLink`. Also your server needs to serve `/orders.html` when `/orders/*` is requested.

Comment: Although it is certainly possible, why not just use **one** application, with routing, and lazy-loading if the size of the bundle is what is bothering you? That would be more efficient, and would make it easy to share code between the various modules of the app.